# Is it possible to change @viewport in css

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm not sure if title is correct or not.

I'm developing a cordova/phonegapp app for windows phone 8 and I want to fit it to screen.

I found that adding this to css:

```
@viewport{height:device-height}
@viewport{width:device-width}
@-ms-viewport{height:device-height}
@-ms-viewport{width:device-width}
```

And this to javascript:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");

    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important;}"
        )
    );

    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            "@-ms-viewport{height:device-height!important;}"
        )
    );

    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}
```

It should fit.

Now it almost fits, and I want to know if it's possible to do something like `height:device-height-3%` and, if so, how I should do this.

To the moment I haven't been able to make it work. Note that I'm noob in windows phone development and almost noob in css/javascript too

Comment: you can try media queries... like this @media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 240px) {...}

Comment: do you want to get 3% height of available viewport height?

Comment: I want to make it a 3% smaller, maybe a 4%, maybe a 5%, I won't know till I start making it smaller and see when it fits screen ;) Of course, I want to keep proportion (ratio)

Answer (score 2):

this may help you

```
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no" />
```